# Access groovy variable in powershell

Tags: html, powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I have created a foldable section controlled by a checkbox using groovy as below

[image: jenkins]

groovy script:

```
        html = 
        '''
        <form>
          Threads:<br>
          <input type="text" name="Threads"><br>
          Duration:<br>
          <input type="text" name="Duration"><br>
          RampUP:<br>
          <input type="text" name="RampUP"><br>
        </form>
        '''
        if (Override_Execution_Details .equals("Yes")) 
        {return html}
```

above code will open the fields as we select the checkbox

[image: ui]
How to access the values of textbox field like threads, duration on my PowerShell code in build section.

I have made some below changes

[image: new]
and tried to access 'Threads' value '1234'
as $env:Threads; But it's not working. Please anyone can assist me.

[image: threadvalue]

Answer (score 0):

You are showing what you built but not what you've tried and either got errors with or had issues with. So, engenders assumptions on our part. So, since you did not provide code to examine, It's a bit of a challenge to give you a code response. Well, that and I have never used or even seen Jenkins, just folks talking about it on the forums/Q&A sites and the like.

PowerShell is not the tool to use for GUI automation. If you try, out of the box, you are limited to SendKeys, but mostly that is for sending stuff to on taking actions on a GUI, which do work, but can be unreliable in several instances.

You seem to be saying you want to copy stuff from the GUI, which you can do with SendKey7s, but again, my previous comment stands. So, you need a GUI automation tool that is more robust. See:

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and it's [PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/) or similar tools, like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Lastly, if it is just HTML, on the back end, you can get to that as long as you know the element you want. Yet, me not knowing anything about Jenkins, this screen shot looks like a fat x86/x64 GUI form. So, you have to access the form elements to get to content, just as you would with WinForms or WPF.

WF example:

```
# build form, take user input, output to screen

 function Get-URL 
 {
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

   $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
   $Form.width = 300
   $Form.height = 110
   $Form.Text = ”Please enter a URL”

   $txtURL = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
   $txtURL.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,7)
   $txtURL.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
   $Form.Controls.Add($txtURL)

   $lblURL = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
   $lblURL.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
   $lblURL.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,20)
   $lblURL.Text = "Please enter a URL:"
   $Form.Controls.Add($lblURL)

   $btnSubmit = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
   $btnSubmit.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
   $btnSubmit.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
   $btnSubmit.Text = "Submit"
   $btnSubmit.Add_Click({Return-Get-URL})
   $form.Controls.Add($btnSubmit)

   $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
   $x = $Form.ShowDialog()
   return $txtURL.Text
 }

function Return-Get-URL 
{ $Form.Close() }

( $url = Get-URL )
```